# elif self.game.puzzle[row][col] == 0: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Im learning how to implement an AI algorithm in sudoku. But my professor required an interface and im new to tkinter python 3.6. I followed the code of newcoder.io tutorial in making sudoku python game but i got an error as you can see at the title. This is my full code. Please need help.

I cant click a cell and set a number while playing the game and got an error.

```
def __cell_clicked(self, event):
        if self.game.game_over:
            return
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        if (MARGIN < x < WIDTH - MARGIN and MARGIN < y < HEIGHT - MARGIN):
            self.canvas.focus_set()

            # get row and col numbers from x,y coordinates
            row, col = (y - MARGIN) / SIDE, (x - MARGIN) / SIDE

            # if cell was selected already - deselect it
            if (row, col) == (self.row, self.col):
                self.row, self.col = -1, -1
            elif self.game.puzzle[row][col] == 0:
                self.row, self.col = row, col
        else:
            self.row, self.col = -1, -1

        self.__draw_cursor()
```

I get this error message:

```
"Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "sudoku.py", line 141, in __cell_clicked
    elif self.game.puzzle[row][col] == 0:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float"
```

Comment: `row, col = (y - MARGIN) / SIDE, (x - MARGIN) / SIDE` - those are floating-point divisions.

Comment: That error looks pretty self-explanatory. I recommend you do a bit of basic debugging to verify that `row` and `column` are what you assume they are. My guess is, they are not.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!